# "Tuning" tr and sed expression

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I have MD5 file which lists filename and MD5 sum in the following way:

```
MD5 (file14n0001.xml.gz) = 04eb2524d271077ec8f1a0021779b171
MD5 (file14n0002.xml.gz) = 07e2b29645e9211cce9daf1ae27e7b99
MD5 (file14n0003.xml.gz) = c31cca187a32743441868822b02d83aa
```

I need to parse out only filename and MD5 sum; for example, the desired output is:

```
file14n0001.xml.gz 04eb2524d271077ec8f1a0021779b171
file14n0002.xml.gz 07e2b29645e9211cce9daf1ae27e7b99
file14n0003.xml.gz c31cca187a32743441868822b02d83aa
```

My tr (augmented with sed) expression is:

```
tr -d 'MD5() ' | sed 's/=/ /g'
```

But tr part of the expression also delete all 5s in lines so the output is

```
file14n0001.xml.gz 04eb224d271077ec8f1a0021779b171
file14n0002.xml.gz 07e2b2964e9211cce9daf1ae27e7b99
file14n0003.xml.gz c31cca187a32743441868822b02d83aa
```

I kindly ask for a pointer how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command:

```
sed -r 's/MD5 .(.*). = (.*)/\1 \2/' filename
```

Output:

```
file14n0001.xml.gz 04eb2524d271077ec8f1a0021779b171
file14n0002.xml.gz 07e2b29645e9211cce9daf1ae27e7b99
file14n0003.xml.gz c31cca187a32743441868822b02d83aa
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `tr`, just use `sed`.

```
sed -r -e 's/^MD5 [(](.+)[)] = ([0-9a-f]+)$/\1 \2/g'
```

Comment: Don't know why it returns `Unmatched ( or \(`?

Comment: My bad, I should have put the code in a code block: this site interpreted some of the characters and did not format it properly. Now fixed

Answer (score 1):

For small files, a pure-bash solution is an option

```
while IFS='() ' read -r _ file_name _ sum; 
do 
   printf '%s %s\n' "$file_name" "$sum"; 
done < file
file14n0001.xml.gz 04eb2524d271077ec8f1a0021779b171
file14n0002.xml.gz 07e2b29645e9211cce9daf1ae27e7b99
file14n0003.xml.gz c31cca187a32743441868822b02d83aa
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the number of columns is fix `awk` and `sed` would be usefull.

```
awk '{print $2,$4}' file.txt  | sed 's@[()]@@g'

foo@bar(~) $ awk '{print $2,$4}' file.txt  | sed 's@[()]@@g'
file14n0001.xml.gz 04eb2524d271077ec8f1a0021779b171
file14n0002.xml.gz 07e2b29645e9211cce9daf1ae27e7b99
file14n0003.xml.gz c31cca187a32743441868822b02d83aa
```

**sort summary:** get the collumns that you want with `awk` and stript the `()` symbols